# Get URL of UIIimagePickerController by using swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm trying to get URL of picked image in `UIIimagePickerController`. But it's getting nil value..

```
passportImageView.image = image
passportButton.setTitle("",for: .normal)
passportButton.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
passportImageURLString = (info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL)?.absoluteString
print(passportImageURLString as Any)
```

Answer (score 0):

to get url of image you must use

```
let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL
```

also you can see other approaches below

```
let imageName = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

**EDIT 1**

to save image in photo gallery use this extension for `PHPhotoLibrary`
http://swiftexample.info/code/phphotolibrary-save-image-swift/

Comment: imageUrl is getting "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @G Sreekanth is that image picked from camera or gallery ?

Comment: image picked from camera

Comment: @G Sreekanth if you picked image from camera it's name will always be nil, because image not saved in photo gallery yet, you need to save it manually with name that do you want.

Comment: @Arther Sahakyan yes, I need to save it manually, I want that code

Comment: @G Sreekanth sorry for late response I edited my answer with example code url